# How to deobfuscate this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, reverse-engineering, deobfuscation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decode obfuscated JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145796/decode-obfuscated-javascript)

Question:

I have the following javascript code:

```
var _0xe91d=["\x28\x35\x28\x24\x29\x7B\x24\x2E\x32\x77\x2E

...


x5F\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x5F\x64\x75\x72\x7C\x76\x5F\x74\x61\x62\x73\x5F\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E\x7C\x76\x5F\x74\x61\x62\x73\x5F\x64\x75\x72\x7C\x76\x5F\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x5F\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x5F\x66\x78\x7C\x74\x61\x62\x5F\x66\x78\x7C\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x7C\x62\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E\x7C\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E\x5F\x7C\x75\x6E\x6D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x77\x68\x65\x65\x6C\x7C\x73\x77\x69\x74\x63\x68\x7C\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x7C\x6A\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];eval(function (_0x173cx1,_0x173cx2,_0x173cx3,_0x173cx4,_0x173cx5,_0x173cx6){_0x173cx5=function (_0x173cx3){return (_0x173cx3<_0x173cx2?_0xe91d[4]:_0x173cx5(parseInt(_0x173cx3/_0x173cx2)))+((_0x173cx3=_0x173cx3%_0x173cx2)>35?String[_0xe91d[5]](_0x173cx3+29):_0x173cx3.toString(36));} ;if(!_0xe91d[4][_0xe91d[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0x173cx3--){_0x173cx6[_0x173cx5(_0x173cx3)]=_0x173cx4[_0x173cx3]||_0x173cx5(_0x173cx3);} ;_0x173cx4=[function (_0x173cx5){return _0x173cx6[_0x173cx5];} ];_0x173cx5=function (){return _0xe91d[7];} ;_0x173cx3=1;} ;while(_0x173cx3--){if(_0x173cx4[_0x173cx3]){_0x173cx1=_0x173cx1[_0xe91d[6]]( new RegExp(_0xe91d[8]+_0x173cx5(_0x173cx3)+_0xe91d[8],_0xe91d[9]),_0x173cx4[_0x173cx3]);} ;} ;return _0x173cx1;} (_0xe91d[0],62,284,_0xe91d[3][_0xe91d[2]](_0xe91d[1]),0,{}));
```

How exactly can I decipher it, and find out what it does ?
And what's the principle behind this obfuscation ?

Comment: First decide the string, but I assume you already did that. Then format it rationally. Then start reading it. Not sure what you mean by "principle", are you asking why it was obfuscated?

Comment: It looks to me as though the code is the genereated output of some sort of automated case design package.  I had to reverse a whole application a good number of years back that was the same sort of thing in C, with all functions and variables being just meaningless numeric names.

Comment: @Dave Newton: You can't just read it with toString, it's encrypted. Fortunately, it must provide the decrypt function in order to use it in eval, which can be intercepted by google-chrome javascript console :)

Comment: What do you mean, it's encrypted? It's hex. Use the "hex" box at http://home.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/. Use toString().

Comment: @Dave Newton: Nonono, it's not just hex. Before the string got hexed, it got encrypted. So in order to reverse it, it needs to get unhexed, and then decrypted. And only afterwards will one have the plain text code. The only thing that isn't encrypted is the decrypt function, and it shows when you do toString. Actually, it does regex substitutions first to get the decrypt function, but that result can be intercepted in the debug console :)

Comment: @Quandary ... So it's just hex, and the "decryption" is right there. I still don't see what the issue is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does some replacement on some text using Regular Expression.
The expression is in hex code, you can use .toString() to bring it back to unicode:
for example:

```
"\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65".toString() : fromCharCode
```

or

```
"\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65".toString() : replace
```

Comment: Funny, .toString() is really info enough. But only in conjunction with a bit of preparing in goole-chrome javascript console, as recommended in the other post. Deciphered in < 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

It's just hex codes in a string \x20 is a space which is decimal 32.

```
print _0xe91d
```

Comment: there is more to it than that - scroll right

Comment: But now you know how to turn it into something other than hex codes. Are you saying you don't understand the the variable names are hex codes as well?
It will only take you 10 minutes to 2 hours depending on your debugging skills to write a script that will change all the hex codes  back into character strings.

Comment: I do understand that - but you're meant to be answering a question or offering insight into the solution. I was pointing out your answer didn't really fulfil that. I don't believe I said anything about _my_ debugging skills, as this question is not about me.

Comment: The question was:

How exactly can I decipher it, and find out what it does ?
And what's the principle behind this obfuscation ?

It was not decipher this for me.

Comment: It's true - your question was a helpful first point - but there was more to it than that. Hence me saying "there is more to it than that"