# what kind of encryption is this? javascript/jQuery Code

Tags: javascript, encode

well i was reading some files i got my hands on and this javascript file had this array that jQuery inside this file is using.

what kind of encryption is this code?

```
var _0xe66d=["\x53\x61\x79\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F","\x47\x65\x74\x43\x6F\x75\x6E\x74","\x4D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65\x20\x3A\x20","\x59\x6F\x75\x20\x61\x72\x65\x20\x77\x65\x6C\x63\x6F\x6D\x65\x2E"];function NewObject(_0xa79fx2){var _0xa79fx3=0;this[_0xe66d[0]]= function(_0xa79fx4){_0xa79fx3++;alert(_0xa79fx2+ _0xa79fx4)};this[_0xe66d[1]]= function(){return _0xa79fx3}}var obj= new NewObject(_0xe66d[2]);obj.SayHello(_0xe66d[3])
```

Comment: It is hex encoded., use https://beautifier.io/ and past this data , you will get decoded data

Comment: I'm getting the data, but when you check the code content, it says _0x5287x4, how can I do that, I couldn't figure out which decimal unit :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wqkc80xd/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode obfuscated JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145796/decode-obfuscated-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The output you show looks like it was a result of using [obfuscator.io](https://obfuscator.io/).

Deobfuscating such a code works only to a certain degree.

You can for sure use a tool like [deobfuscate.io](https://deobfuscate.io/). This results in this:

```js
function NewObject(_0xa79fx2) {
  var _0xa79fx3 = 0;
  this.SayHello = function (_0xa79fx4) {
    _0xa79fx3++;
    alert(_0xa79fx2 + _0xa79fx4);
  };
  this.GetCount = function () {
    return _0xa79fx3;
  };
}
var obj = new NewObject("Message : ");
obj.SayHello("You are welcome.");
```

But such tools can't recover the original variable or parameter names because those have been replaced in the obfuscation process. And there is no way to get those back.

Comment: _0x5287x4'preventDefault'; onları çözemiyorum :(

Comment: @MusaPekel How is `_0x5287x4'preventDefault';` related to the code you show in your question. And to the deobfuscated one I show here?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand :(

Comment: @MusaPekel what part of the answer do you not understand? The code you show in your question is obfuscated by the tool I show in my answer. And I showed you how it looks unobfuscated using the other tool. And the code does not have `_0x5287x4'preventDefault'` anywhere.

Comment: $("#UzmanYazar-Net").on("click", function (_0x5287x4) {
    _0x5287x4.preventDefault(); I check the same but it doesn't provide solution

Comment: @t.niese, it seems he has two code snippets going on in this question. The original he posted, and another below as an answer. The other post shows entirely different code, which includes the `_0x5287x4'preventDefault'`, that he's asking about. @MusaPekel - as I commented elsewhere, `_0x5287x4` is the "event" object.

Comment: so how can i find that the actual code content is there :) @Jack

Comment: @MusaPekel even if you talk about the code you show in [jsfiddle.net/wqkc80xd](https://jsfiddle.net/wqkc80xd). Use the tool I mention in my answer [deobfuscate.io](https://deobfuscate.io/), past that code from the jsfiddle into it, and you get the unobfuscated code. And there is no such problem that you mention.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/br2mpa0y/ It took a shape that was not like you said

Comment: @MusaPekel but what do you want to fix there?  `_0x5287x4` is a parameter name. Take a look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/) of the jQuery library to see what it is (there you can see that it is an `event`). As I said, deobfuscators can't restore variable names, you need to guess them, or figure out what a good name could be.

Comment: I may have been blind all morning ok now I get it :) Thanks 
I changed it to _0x5287x4 event :)

Comment: @MusaPekel  `_0x5287x4` is just a randomly generated variable name. You can name it however you want `evt`, `event`, `oooooo`, `whatever`. What the purpose of the variable is, is something you need to figure out yourself, and then rename it with a better readable one. There can be multiple variables with the name `_0x5287x4` which could have different meanings.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be it is hex encoded. You can use third party websites to decode it.

```
 https://beautifier.io
```

Comment: I'm getting the data, but when you check the code content, it says _0x5287x4, how can I do that, I couldn't figure out which decimal unit :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wqkc80xd/